# Hard coding if statements in templates

Tags: python, django, database, if-statement

I have been working on an e-commerce website for a while. There three types of products there: Clothes, Accessories and Shoes. There is item table and category table. In the category table are the category objects(clothes,accessories, shoes) which maybe in the near future won't be changed. In my case i don't want accessories to have sizes. So when i am rendering the templates i do if statement which checks if the item's category is accessory. If it is I don't render the size field's value(which is null). Everything works good but i think that there is a better way to achieve this functionality without hard coding the if statement. Can you give me an advice for improving the code?

models.py

```
class ItemCategory(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Item(models.Model):
    seller = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(ItemCategory, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    price_negotiable = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    discount_price = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    size = models.ForeignKey(Size, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    condition = models.CharField(choices=CONDITION_CHOICES, max_length=9)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
```

```
{% if item.category.category != 'accessories' %}
    Size: {{ item.size.size }}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That approach looks normal to me. You could also just not pass any `size` data for accessories in the backend too. Either way you would need to sort the data in front-end or backend as you are trying to achieve it. If you will have to exclude more than one item than `accessories` in future, you might want to move your checks into backend. Then you can use `list` to store all excluded categories and check if item is in the list

```
if category not in category_exclusion_list:
    # do something
```

Generally you would want complex data filtering or processing to happen in the Backend. Especially because it will be cleaner, easier to read and plus it will support more functionalities, plus python jinja2 does not support everything python does iirc.

Comment: Maybe it will be a good approach to write a method belonging to the Item class which checks if the category is ''accessory'' and returns True or False.

Comment: If you only have accessory, than yes it will be also good solution. However, if in future you need to exclude more than just "accessory" from it, then you may need to consider my solution with exclusion list.